# bounded-queue-thread-pool threads not getting terminated on jboss shutdown

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x, threadpool

I have created a bounded-queue-thread-pool in Jboss 7.2.0 standalone.xml as follows:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:threads:1.1">
    <bounded-queue-thread-pool name="myThreadPool">
    <core-threads count="6000"/>
    <queue-length count="1000"/>
    <max-threads count="6000"/>
    <keepalive-time time="60" unit="seconds"/>
    </bounded-queue-thread-pool>
</subsystem>
```

After that I am using this as executor in AJP connectors as follows:

```
<connector name="conn1" protocol="AJP/1.3" scheme="http" socket-binding="conn1" enabled="true" max-post-size="0" executor="myThreadPool" max-connections="2000"/>
<connector name="conn2" protocol="AJP/1.3" scheme="http" socket-binding="conn2" enabled="true" executor="myThreadPool" max-connections="2000"/>
<connector name="conn3" protocol="AJP/1.3" scheme="http" socket-binding="conn3" enabled="true" executor="myThreadPool" max-connections="2000"/>
```

At the end the socket binding for 3 connectors:

```
<socket-binding name="conn1" port="15007"/>
<socket-binding name="conn2" port="15008"/>
<socket-binding name="conn3" port="15009"/>
```

When I start jboss and create multiple http requests, each request thread is created as `myThreadPool-threads-1`, `myThreadPool-threads-2` etc. However when I shutdown jboss using command line, these threads are not getting terminated. Here is the command I use to shutdown:

```
%JBOSS_HOME%\bin\jboss-cli.bat --connect controller=10.10.54.85:9999 --commands=:shutdown
```

Due to this, the java process of jboss-AS is not getting killed. However when I simply remove the `executor` from `connector`, the java process is terminated successfully. Can someone suggest me how to terminated all the threads of threadPool when server is shutdown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably [this bug](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFLY-862) is a cause of your problem, a workaround is set:

```
org.apache.coyote.ajp.DEFAULT_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT
```

Add the following to your `system-properties` in your `host.xml`, `standalone.xml` or `domain.xml`:

```
<system-properties>
    <property name="org.apache.coyote.ajp.DEFAULT_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT" value="600000"/>
<system-properties>
```

this works except if we continuously send request to the server.

See also: [server hang during shutdown when specifying executor in connector](https://developer.jboss.org/message/766336)